# SQLite able to remove referenced row when ON DELETE RESTRICT is set

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have a table with a column like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY("StorageFk") REFERENCES "Storage"("StoragePk") ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

When I use "DB Browser (SQLite)", I cannot delete a row which is referenced by this foreign key, which is what I want. However, when I run this query in my node.js app:

```
DELETE FROM Storage WHERE StoragePk is $1
```

($1 is a placeholder) the row gets deleted. When I open DB Browser after that, it informs me some foreign keys are pointing to a non existing row.

How is this possible?

My full code is this:

```
db.run('DELETE FROM Storage WHERE StoragePk is ?', storageId, function (err) {
    const changes = this.changes;
    db.close(() => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        else if (!changes) {
            reject(`Could not find Storage with id ${storageId}.`);
        }
        else {
            resolve('OK');
        }
    });
});
```

This resolves to 'OK' when I call it a `storageId` of a referenced row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you open a sqlite database, you have to explicitly enable foreign key enforcement with

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

[Documentation link](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).